# Windows 8 metro app works properly on Visual Studio but not on tablet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8

I am developing a Windows 8 metro app where the main screen just has a button. On clicking the button, the app navigates to another frame where all the work is done (which includes reading from files in local storage).

The app works perfectly when I hit run on local machine from Visual Studio 2013. However, if I try running it from the start menu, the main screen opens, but clicking the start button does not cause the app to navigate to the 2nd frame.

*This app was working fine (even when I ran it from start menu) for the last month. I changed some code (things that happen in the 2nd frame and should not affect main screen) and now I am having this issue.

*I am pretty sure that clicking the 'start' button causes the code on the 2nd frame to run,even though it appears to do nothing. I suspect this because if the file that is to be read in the 2nd frame is not in the directory, the app crashes.

I would greatly appreciate any help. I am pretty new to this and am not even sure how to debug an application that's not being run from an IDE.

Comment: capture a crash dump with prcdump (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) (**procdump -ma -i C:\dumps**) on the tablet . Now analyze the dmp file in Windbg (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046)

Comment: Thank you. Since it is going to take some time I will try it over the weekend. I did narrow it down a bit. There is a part where I asynchronously read from a file. If I delete that part and hardcode the file info into the app, it works fine both inside and outside VS. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: post some code pieces.