# 0xC000027B exception in store UWP app (Windows.UI.XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, windbg

I've an C#/UWP-app in beta-release in the Microsoft App-Store. Most of the users have no problems with the App, but for one user the app is crashing on startup. You can't even see the Splash-Screen (it should be displaying a logo or color, however it is white).

In the eventlog this genreic event is logged:

> 0xc000027b (Windows.UI.XAML)

The only difference is, that his Windows-10 Build differs from the other users (10.0.10240 vs 10.0.10586). However, I've collected the crashdumps ("minidumps") and tried to follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump/) tutorial.
If i try this command:

```
dt <Parameter[0]> combase!_STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_HEADER*
```

Windbg gives me this:

> Memory read error (at Parameter[0])

Actually I've integrated the hockey-sdk for automatic crash-reports, but it doesn't report me that specific crash in the dashboard.

How can I trace down this crash?

**Update:**
I've managed to get the Call-Stack with PDE:

```
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::PropertyPathListener::GetValue+0x3e
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::BindingExpression::GetValue+0xbb
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetValueExpression+0x24b
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetBindingCore+0x56
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetBindingCallback+0x146
Windows_UI_Xaml!CBinding::SetBinding+0x48
Windows_UI_Xaml!XamlNativeRuntime::SetValue+0x4c2
Windows_UI_Xaml!BinaryFormatObjectWriter::SetValueOnCurrentInstance+0x1ad
Windows_UI_Xaml!BinaryFormatObjectWriter::WriteNode+0x144a
Windows_UI_Xaml!CTemplateContent::LoadXbfVersion2+0xd1
Windows_UI_Xaml!CTemplateContent::Load+0x4d
Windows_UI_Xaml!CFrameworkTemplate::LoadContent+0x270
Windows_UI_Xaml!CControlTemplate::LoadContent+0x18
Windows_UI_Xaml!CFrameworkElement::ApplyTemplate+0x30a
Windows_UI_Xaml!CContentControl::ApplyTemplate+0x20
Windows_UI_Xaml!CFrameworkElement::InvokeApplyTemplate+0x17f
Windows_UI_Xaml!CFrameworkElement::MeasureCore+0x2a3
Windows_UI_Xaml!CUIElement::MeasureInternal+0x1cb
Windows_UI_Xaml!CUIElement::Measure+0x598
Windows_UI_Xaml!CGrid::MeasureOverride+0x307
Windows_UI_Xaml!CFrameworkElement::MeasureCore+0x707
Windows_UI_Xaml!CUIElement::MeasureInternal+0x1cb
Windows_UI_Xaml!CUIElement::Measure+0x598
Windows_UI_Xaml!CGrid::MeasureOverride+0x307
Windows_UI_Xaml!CFrameworkElement::MeasureCore+0x707
```

This would mean, that I've somewhere an incorrect binding?

Comment: Nothing ever pretty happens when an app fails because unmanaged code died, the ultimate Achilles heel of UWP.  Otherwise the exact same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412334/trying-to-debug-windows-store-app-from-dump-files).  People have messed-up machine, you get to see that, don't try to fix all of their problems.  The minidump does not include their address :)

Comment: you need a full dump and use the PDE.dll from my answer that is in the linked question.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Unfortunately, the link is dead (404).

Comment: try this link: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&id=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&cid=DAE128BD454CF957 Get the PDEv10.zip

Comment: does PDE help you to debug it?

Comment: Your crash dump might not have enough info: [How to take a good crash dump for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net). See also [Channel 9 about stowed exceptions](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-64-Windows-81-Store-App-Crash-c000027b)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for providing the PDE, I've updated the question

Comment: this is a databinding issue.check your code where you bind data to controls.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Beside resharper, is there any tool to check the binding? I've only limited access to the computer where the problem occurs, therefore I can't use the "try and error" method

Comment: I don't do XAML coding (still old WinForms) so try to find it on your own