# combase.dll error while running Windows 8.1 App in tablet device

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I have developed a Windows 8.1 App and my client is going to use it on a tablet device. My app runs perfectly fine when the tablet is connected to Wifi but it crashes every time on launch when the tablet is connected to the 3G/4G network using SIM card. When I checked in **EventViewer**, it showed as *Application Error and in the description, it showed combase.dll error*. Even I debug app using Remote Machine in Visual Studio 2015 and it doesn't give any error. My app is Release version with AnyCPU configuration.

Can someone suggest what can be issue?

Comment: create a crash dump (full dump) and analyze it with windbg: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks this post helped a lot. Please post this as answer. Will accept it

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug Store App crashes, generate a full dump (with procdump configured as post mortem debugger: `procdump -ma -i C:\localdumps`)

Now open the dmp in Windbg (part of the Windows 10 SDK), [configure the debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and use the [Windbg Extension PDE.dll](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&authkey=!AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&ithint=folder%2czip) from [Andrew Richards](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrew_richards/) to list all Stowed Exceptions (those 0xC000027B exceptions) with `!PDE.dpx -dse` to :

```
0:006> !PDE.dpx -dse
Start memory scan  : 0x0551fc7c ($csp)
End memory scan    : 0x05520000 (User Stack Base)

0x0551fc94 : 0x012db914 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
0x0551fcdc : 0x0163c168 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
```

Now use !PDE.dse  to display its data:

```
0:006> !PDE.dse 0551fc94
Stowed Exception Array @ 0x0551fc94

Stowed Exception #1 @ 0x012db914
    0x80070005 (FACILITY_WIN32 - Win32 Undecorated Error Codes): E_ACCESSDENIED - General access denied error

    Stack    : 0x163c528
        770ba9f1 combase!RoOriginateLanguageException+0x3b
        6f137872 clr!SetupErrorInfo+0x1e1
        6f1fbc91 clr!MarshalNative::GetHRForException_WinRT+0x7d

>>> Associated CLR Exception <<<

Exception object: 02b424f8
Exception type:   System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message:          <Invalid Object>
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    00000000 00000001 UNKNOWN!UNKNOWN+0x2
    0551FC58 015702E9 CryptoQuoteW8cs!UNKNOWN+0x81
```

This shows the content of the exception with the associated CLR exception.