# uwp app and unhandled exception

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, unhandled-exception, hockeyapp

I created a Universal Windows Platform app for Windows 10 desktop. I'm using HockeyApp for logging my events and exceptions. I [uploaded pdb symbols](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application) to my HockeyApp account.
I got an unhandled exception, this is the log:

```
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xe6890f
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x699af7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xb41a69
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x699af7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xb3c820
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x699af7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xb3810a
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x699af7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xbc7a30
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x699af7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xbd4dc3
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x699af7
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xe68fc9
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4ba96e
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xf22ade
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x50c81a
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0x10227bb
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x69993e
MyLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x497d7c
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xb1c72c
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xb1c6e6
MyApp!<BaseAddress>+0xb1c614
         Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)
```

How can I use this information? How do I find the real reason for this exception? Any ideas?

Comment: get a dump and debug the dmp with Windbg: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046

Comment: Please contact support@hockeyapp.net so they can help