# [UWP][C#] My app is unhealthy

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-store

I have a UWP app published to the Store and works great. The latest version I submitted to the store worked fine in Debug and Release builds locally, it passes the Windows App Cert Kit tests, it passes the Store certification process but it crash at runtime when I (or everyone else) download it from the store. The Store's Health report gives me a useless (at least for me) stack trace. What I did to fix the issue was to submit a previous version and guess what... same errors, that submit was the previous, working version. Here is the stack trace from the Health report:

```
Frame   Image   Function    Offset
0   KERNELBASE.dll  RaiseFailFastException  0x0000000000000074  
1   mrt100_app.dll  System::Runtime::EH.GetRuntimeException 0x0000000000000014  
2   mrt100_app.dll  System::Runtime::EH.GetClasslibException    0x0000000000000045  
3   mrt100_app.dll  System::Runtime::EH.RhThrowHwEx 0x0000000000000063  
4   mrt100_app.dll  RhpThrowHwEx2   0x0000000000000000  
5   mrt100_app.dll  System::Runtime::TypeCast.AreTypesEquivalentInternal    0x0000000000000071  
6   mrt100_app.dll  System::Runtime::TypeCast.AreTypesEquivalent    0x0000000000000009  
7   null            Internal::Runtime::TypeLoader::RuntimeTypeHandleEqualityComparer.Equals 0x0000000000000047  
8   null            System::Collections::Generic::Internal::Dictionary$2_System::RuntimeTypeHandle,System::Int32_.FindEntry 0x0000000000000096  
9   null            System::Collections::Generic::Internal::Dictionary$2_System::RuntimeTypeHandle,System::Int32_.TryGetValue   0x0000000000000011  
10  null            System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgModuleManager.InsertDataIntoDictionary 0x0000000000000089  
11  null            System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgModuleManager.Initialize   0x0000000000000240  
12  myapp.mcginterop.dll    Mcg::StartupCodeTrigger.Initialize  0x0000000000000038  
**13    myapp.exe       $ILCT$::$ILT$MainMethodType$.NewMainMethod  0x000000000000000B**    
14  myapp.dll       RHBinder__ManagedInitAndLaunch  0x0000000000000020  
15  myapp.dll       RHBinder__ShimExeMain   0x000000000000000D  
16  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk 0x0000000000000014  
17  ntdll.dll       RtlUserThreadStart  0x0000000000000021
```

Comment: [generate a crash dump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a PC where you downloaded the app and use [Windbg + PDE.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046) to see the a better stack

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to diagnose this issue by the above stack trace. You'd better open a support [ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support). You will get 1:1 support on that. Please kindly note that your support ticket will be free if it is Microsoft's issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi Xavier. I did opened a ticket and this was the answer "This issue surpasses our support and would suggest to post your question on the Tech Forums to get advice from one of our technical advisors" ‍♂️

Comment: Have you tried to sideload your app to see if it will crash when you generate package successfully?