# UWP app crashes after upgrade to Windows 10-1809

Tags: uwp, windows-10, sideloading

Our UWP app starts crashing after I upgraded the Windows to 1809. It works just fine on 1803 but as soon as it is installed on the machine with 1809 it crashes. We use Office 365 API for authentication and authorization. The app crashes only when you give it a valid username/password combo meaning the authentication piece is working but something happens when it tries to move beyond authentication. The app is side loaded as it is an LOB app. Any idea what needs to change from 1803 to 1809 to make it work?

Comment: Try to change target version of project to 1809

Comment: Have you checked the event view to see the crash info about your app? Is it possible for you to remote debug your app on 1809 so that you may be able to find more details?

Comment: I believe the issue is with setting the version as @shubham has suggested. We will recreate a new package with a special attention to min/max. Will do the event view if problem persists and will update here about our findings accordingly.

Comment: create a crash dump and [analyze the dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046)

Comment: We changed the max version to 1809 but the issue still remains. Will try the other routes and share our findings.

Comment: [use in Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal) the Crash data entry, select your sideloaded app and configure it to create a dump. analyze the dump with windbg as I already linked.

Comment: It looks like there was an issue for one of the Syncfusion XAML libraries. They have provided a patch that is supposed to fix it. I shall report if it does.