# UWP App crashes for the first time and not every time Exception thrown at 0x06515AE7 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll)

Tags: uwp, windows-8.1, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, windows-8.1-universal

mine is huge application so that i cannot share the code of the application i'm getting error while doing clicking or any events in the page i'm not able to trace the exception in any case while adding all exceptions in settings and enabled native debugging getting error as "Exception thrown at 0x06515AE7 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in MingleChat.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

An unhandled win32 exception of vs 2017"

Comment: There is not enough information here to diagnose this. Can you try attaching the windbg debugger to the running app to see if it provides better crash information?

Comment: [use in Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal) the Crash data entry, select your sideloaded app and configure it to create a dump. analyze the [dump with windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046)

Comment: Extracted crash log from microsoft store pfa in the below link.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ex7j3unc1y77zmm/stackTrace.tsv?dl=0)

Comment: again, do what I said, create a crash dump and analyze the dmp with windbg

Comment: The .tsv file doesn't contain enough information. What you want is the actual dump file (.dmp). Easy to create if you can reproduce the crash with windbg attached (or via Device Portal as suggested in other comments).

Answer (score 0):

@Harish,

Does any of your Xaml markup include the following setting?

`FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{x:Null}"`

or perhaps any of the other FocusVisual properties being set to null like

`FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{x:Null}"`

We were getting a very similar error message and observing a similar crashing behavior with our UWP application as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701841/what-is-causing-uwp-app-to-intermittently-crash-and-throw-windows-ui-xaml-dllcf).

And that Null setting was the culprit in our case.

Comment: @HarishKinthali did you find any occurrences in your xaml of setting FocusVisualPrimaryBrush to Null?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your min sdk version to 15xxx.