# Xamarin.Forms UWP application crashes on start

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I built a Xamarin.Forms app. When I run the UWP version, it works on simulator, but when I install it on my Windows 10 machine from AppCenter, it crashes after splash screen. The same thing happens on a Surface tablet. iOS and Android both work fine. Here is what I see in the Event Viewer:

> Application: MyApp.UWP.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: exception code e06d7363, exception address 75D9FD82 Stack:
>
> Faulting application name: MyApp.UWP.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5dbc5c1c Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.17763.652, time stamp: 0x57e2061a Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0011fd82 Faulting process id: 0x49ec Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d590e87959548f Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\818F3EF5.MyApp_4.0.1226.0_x86__gkbk8c6n1cpxt\MyApp.UWP.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   2b637e04-8d94-4651-9b19-fa8b0bc91743 Faulting package full name:
>   818F3EF5.MyApp_4.0.1226.0_x86__gkbk8c6n1cpxt Faulting package-relative
>   application ID: App
>
> Fault bucket 1339835817727291998, type 5 
>   Event Name: MoAppCrash
>   Response: Not available 
>   Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1:
>   818F3EF5.MyApp_4.0.1226.0_x86__gkbk8c6n1cpxt P2: praid:App
>   P3: 1.0.0.0 P4: 5dbc5c1c P5: KERNELBASE.dll P6: 10.0.17763.652 P7:
>   57e2061a P8: e0434352 P9: 0011fd82 P10:
>
> Attached files:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER45C5.tmp.mdmp
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER471E.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER47AB.tmp.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER47A9.tmp.csv
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER47E9.tmp.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_818F3EF5.MyApp_24da81352882147d9bc94d42470a2ff1eda6615_f8efac89_037c4e60
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   2b637e04-8d94-4651-9b19-fa8b0bc91743 Report Status: 268435456 Hashed
>   bucket: f6c4afba0540ebc5f2980d93d4faf25e Cab Guid: 0

Any idea on what could cause this?

Comment: create a crash dump and [analyze the dmp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046)

Comment: @magicandre1981 No new dmp appears after crash. Is it the right folder?

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\CrashDumps

Comment: you need to [configure Windows to generate dumps with device portal under "crash data"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-desktop) for the sideloaded app

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't connect to the Device Portal in the browser. I use localhost, as the app is installed on my machine. Isn't there a detailed step by step instruction?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have got my dump. It is not very descriptive though. ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception) 

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

Comment: what do you see in callstack? Also try to analyze the dmp with [DebugDiag Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump)

Comment: I tried it with DebugDiag after trying WinDbg, the result is similar:

ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+c    
ntdll!TppWorkerThread+296    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+19    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+2f    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b

Comment: The app crashes even when I run it on VS in release mode. It was silly of me not to try release at the beginning of the issue. I will open a new thread on it. Thank you very much for your help. If you make your suggestions an answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: I already posted an answer about the topic. I makes no sense to post the same information twice