# The program has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b) for UWP apps

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp

I have been developing a UWP app for awhile now. No problems at all. Have it connected to a git repo and everything. So this solution and project was working perfectly fine on 3 days ago. I finished working for the day, made a commit to the repo and turned off my computer. When I came back today, tried to launch my UWP in visual studio 2019 to start debugging on local machine I got this message:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
>   The program '[2812] LaserMeasurementTool.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
>   Activation of the Windows Store app '062a9632-d22f-4d48-991a-d1d51afe77e5_ebvsp9khn4a7w!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.

[image: Error message 1]

Sometimes right after the 0xc000007b error code it says "a dll could not be found" but not every time.

I have tried so far:

- Clean and rebuild the solution
- Repair Visual Studio

I see that there is lots of people that have has this problem. But none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. Was wondering if there is more I can do to solve this issue. I can't do very much if I cannot run my program to test it.

Thank you so much in advance!

**Update**

Since the first post of this I have tried a few more things:
I have changed the debugger in VS 2019 to native only. This prompted a different error dialog
[image: Error message 2]

After this I was taken to [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh972445(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) by clicking on "help"

This page got me to open my event viewer for more detail on the issue and this was what the event viewer gave me:

> Activation for 062a9632-d22f-4d48-991a-d1d51afe77e5_ebvsp9khn4a7w!App failed. Error code: The app didn't start.. Activation phase: COM ActivateExtension

And finally the output window in VS 2019 at this point read this:

> 'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\lav-dc1\Folder Redirection\bwhelan\Documents\Source\Repos\132 Laser Measurement Tool\LaserMeasurementTool\LaserMeasurementToolUWP\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\LaserMeasurementTool.exe'. 
>   'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.2_2.2.27902.3_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\uwphost.dll'. 
>   'LaserMeasurementTool.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.2_2.2.27902.3_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\uwphost.dll'
>   The thread 0x3b30 has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
>   The thread 0x1208 has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
>   The program '[15228] LaserMeasurementTool.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).

As a whole it still does not work I figured I would add these are things I have now tried and that fail for my situation.

**UPDATE CSPROJ FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>Removed for safety</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>LaserMeasurementTool</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>LaserMeasurementTool</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>Removed for safety</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WindowsXamlEnableOverview>true</WindowsXamlEnableOverview>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>false</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
    <AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA256</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <EnableGatekeeperAnalysis>false</EnableGatekeeperAnalysis>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>false</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\DataModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ExportModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ImportModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\LoginModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ProgramDataModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\SettingsModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utilities\CollectionConverter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utilities\ExcelBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utilities\JSON.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utilities\Messages.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utilities\DataHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\AdminViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\CalibrationViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\DatabaseViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\GeneralViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\LoginChangePasswordViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\LoginViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\MainDisplayViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\SettingsViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\AdminAccountView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AdminAccountView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\Admin\AddAccount.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AddAccount.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\Admin\EditAccount.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>EditAccount.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\Admin\MainAccount.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainAccount.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\ChangePasswordView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ChangePasswordView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\General\Calibration.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Calibration.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\General\Database.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Database.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\General\Main.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Main.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\General\Settings.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Settings.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\LoginView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>LoginView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\MainView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\GeneralView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>GeneralView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\TestView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>TestView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Add.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Add_DarkGray.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Add_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\BackBtn.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\BackBtn_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Checkmark.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Checkmark_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\LaveerLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Load.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Load_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Lock.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\LogoutBtn.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\LogoutBtn_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Person.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Plus.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Plus_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\RemoveBtn.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\EditBtn.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\EditBtn_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Lock_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\RemoveBtn_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Sync.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Sync_Shadow.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Sync_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\X.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\X_LightGray.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\X_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LoginBackground.jpg" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\Person_White.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\img\ViewBtn.png" />
    <Content Include="Properties\Default.rd.xml" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Styles\Styles.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\AdminAccountView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\Admin\AddAccount.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\Admin\EditAccount.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\Admin\MainAccount.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\ChangePasswordView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\General\Calibration.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\General\Database.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\General\Main.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\General\Settings.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\LoginView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\MainView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\GeneralView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\TestView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler">
      <Version>2.2.3</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR">
      <Version>2.0.8</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.Native">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.9</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MvvmLight">
      <Version>5.4.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MvvmLightLibs">
      <Version>5.4.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>12.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.DataGridExcelExport.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Licensing">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Pdf.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.SfGauge.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.SfGrid.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.SfInput.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.XlsIO.UWP">
      <Version>17.3.0.28</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe">
      <Version>4.6.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '14.0' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: If you download the latest project from github and run it, will the same issue occur? If receiving the same problem, try again the previous commit version in addition to the latest project.

Comment: 0xc000007b is Stowed Exception (wrapped exception). generate crash dump and [analyze the dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this problem before, it is kind of elusive. Try to close Visual Studio and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the folder. This should make sure there are no leftovers (sometimes Clean Solution is not enough). Then uninstall the installed version of your application from the PC via Start menu, so you can install from clean slate.

If this does not help, I have found several reports that this problem occurred when an invalid `App.config` file was in the project folder. Check there is no `App.config` file, if yes, then try deleting it.

If both these approaches fail, please also try cloning the project to a different location and trying again. Make sure the path to the project is not too long (this problem is less prominent today, but it still **does** happen, that things fail without a clear reason just because the `bin` file path is too deep).

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you very much for your answer. I tried both your approaches and these were the results: After removing the obj and bin and uninstalling. I ran it again for the first time (with debugger on native still) and I got an IO exception saying it could not find the the appxmanifest.xml file in my project. I could not find one of these either. Only a Package.appxmanifest. But after generating it in the bin again, that errors goes away and I get the same errors as my updated section above. I could not locate any App.config in my solution folder.

Comment: Also, moved my project to the desktop and tried this again with no success

Comment: Could you please update your question with the contents of your project's `csproj`? Of course, please hide all sensitive information before posting. I am especially interested in how the `Package.appxmanifest` is included there

Comment: Update includes the csproj file

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see anything inherently wrong with the csproj contents... Do you have an alternative device on which you could try to compile your app? Or potentially a virtual machine? Also, can you try temporarily disabling your antivirus software if that is not interfering with the installation somehow?

Comment: So there has been a development. Today, I decided to try it on another computer like you suggested. So I fetched from my repo again to try and run on another machine. In the mean time, I tried it one more time with fresh repo pull on the problem computer. And it just worked. I have NO clue how or why this has occured, because the only difference between last repo commit and the project I had been using one the change of one control. Either way I won't complain. Thank you very much for your help. I wish there was a better explanation to this elusive problem

Comment: I can't directly explain the reason, but if you first delete the project in your computer and then download the latest project from github, will it work?

Comment: After a mandatory windows update last night, and the error occurring again, I think I can safely say the issue is with Windows 10 Build 19013 somehow deleting or moving some relevant dll that Visual Studio doesn't know how to deal with. After reverting back to older windows build 1903 it works fine.

Comment: If you could find a way to provide a Github repo on which it fails, I could try to forward it to teams behind UWP