# Store version of UWP Package with a full trust process forms app keeps crashing on launch

Tags: winforms, uwp, .net-standard-2.0, .net-runtime

I have a UWP app with a full trust win32 forms app bundled with it.

My project structure is like

> UWP App
>
> Win32 Forms App (.NET Framework 4.7.2)
>
> Sync Library (.NET Framework 4.7.2) - referred by Forms App
>
> Domain Library (.NET Standard 2.0) - referred by both UWP App and Sync Library.

When I get a release build through visual studio, it works fine. But when the same package is published to the store, app keeps crashing on launch. I tried adding crash logs by subscribing to the App.UnhandledException. But it is not being fired. Also in the store health report, It is just shown as "unknown".
[image: Store health report]

On checking the error logs in Event viewer, there were two errors thrown for each crash which are listed below.

```
Source: .NET Runtime  
Application: MyAppName.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code e06d7363, exception address 00007FFB4D3DA859
Stack:
```

The other one is

```
Source: Application Error
Faulting application name: MyAppName.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5e922c6f
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.752, time stamp: 0x2023e189
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000003a859
Faulting process id: 0x2f4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6109e2c207537
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj\MyAppName.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 6cdeefcb-e2cb-4b77-ae28-1c0b54fb41ff
Faulting package full name: AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Windows Error Report:

```
Version=1
EventType=MoAppCrash
EventTime=132311532032811137
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=132311532035982658
ReportStatus=268435456
ReportIdentifier=0f767db9-4d2d-451f-acaa-efddb8b3225d
IntegratorReportIdentifier=67b702fb-992c-4ddf-b31e-eebfa70d328c
Wow64Host=34404
NsAppName=praid:App
OriginalFilename=MyAppName.exe
AppSessionGuid=000036c0-0001-01ab-f765-5d2aa310d601
TargetAppId=U:AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj!App
TargetAppVer=0.5.22.0_x64_!2020//04//11:20:45:35!0!MyAppName.exe
BootId=4294967295
ServiceSplit=1332998561
TargetAsId=1483
IsFatal=1
EtwNonCollectReason=4
Response.BucketId=d5c24af9f45a79f600894a99f9fb0fc3
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=1191565601600638915
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Package Full Name
Sig[0].Value=AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj
Sig[1].Name=Application Name
Sig[1].Value=praid:App
Sig[2].Name=Application Version
Sig[2].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[3].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[3].Value=5e922c6f
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[4].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[5].Value=10.0.18362.752
Sig[6].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[6].Value=2023e189
Sig[7].Name=Exception Code
Sig[7].Value=e0434352
Sig[8].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[8].Value=000000000003a859
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.18362.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=16393
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=ab6f
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=ab6f94a45a680442bf911fba1b09d517
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=7e29
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=7e29e5215127ef7af2317cd3c1a7d6cf
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj\MyAppName.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj\MyAppName.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\psapi.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\cea8b8fbc469dcbc6224d523a578e4b3\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WinTypes.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runtime\ecf16dcbbc95961331f8ec542cb7c3d9\System.Runtime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runtbff93e24#\7fd43d0605b1366bc071e2bbdde312cf\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.staterepositorycore.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextInputFramework.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\InputHost.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcp47mrm.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RMCLIENT.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
OsInfo[0].Value=10
OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
OsInfo[1].Value=0
OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
OsInfo[2].Value=18362
OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
OsInfo[3].Value=753
OsInfo[4].Key=versp
OsInfo[4].Value=0
OsInfo[5].Key=arch
OsInfo[5].Value=9
OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
OsInfo[6].Value=1033
OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
OsInfo[7].Value=113
OsInfo[8].Key=sku
OsInfo[8].Value=48
OsInfo[9].Key=domain
OsInfo[9].Value=1
OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
OsInfo[10].Value=256
OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
OsInfo[11].Value=1
OsInfo[12].Key=platid
OsInfo[12].Value=10
OsInfo[13].Key=sr
OsInfo[13].Value=0
OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
OsInfo[14].Value=468257
OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
OsInfo[15].Value=1
OsInfo[16].Key=iever
OsInfo[16].Value=11.719.18362.0-11.0.180
OsInfo[17].Key=portos
OsInfo[17].Value=0
OsInfo[18].Key=ram
OsInfo[18].Value=32503
OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
OsInfo[19].Value=169
OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
OsInfo[20].Value=0
OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
OsInfo[21].Value=190318
OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
OsInfo[22].Value=1202
OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
OsInfo[23].Value=19h1_release
OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
OsInfo[24].Value=0
OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
OsInfo[25].Value=0
OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
OsInfo[26].Value=0
OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
OsInfo[27].Value=0
OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
OsInfo[28].Value=0
OsInfo[29].Key=osver
OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.18362.753.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
OsInfo[30].Value=36b36b71-1da5-4320-8877-4d60bb3d78e6
OsInfo[31].Key=edition
OsInfo[31].Value=Professional
OsInfo[32].Key=ring
OsInfo[32].Value=Retail
OsInfo[33].Key=expid
OsInfo[34].Key=containerid
OsInfo[35].Key=containertype
OsInfo[36].Key=edu
OsInfo[36].Value=0
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=MoAppCrash
AppName=MyAppName
AppPath=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppPackageFullName_0.5.22.0_x64__krk5891pf20rj\MyAppName.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=C9FF5F66D2724FC9A354189F5DB43763
MetadataHash=-1857492785
```

How to resolve this error?

Crash dump analysis with WinDbg

```
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Bookmark It.exe
DEBUG_FLR_EXCEPTION_CODE(80070002) and the ".exr -1" ExceptionCode(e0434352) don't match

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 12

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on KUMAR-4031

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 84

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 147

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : CLR.Engine
    Value: CLR

    Key  : CLR.System.IO.FileNotFoundException._fileName
    Value: System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

    Key  : CLR.System.IO.FileNotFoundException._message
    Value: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

    Key  : CLR.Version
    Value: 4.0.30319.0

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 855

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 2


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000000000003 rbx=00000000e0434352 rcx=00000043cf7fe890
rdx=00007ffc95c570f8 rsi=0000000000000001 rdi=0000000000000005
rip=00007ffca6d0a859 rsp=00000043cf7fee80 rbp=00000043cf7ff8c0
 r8=00000043cf7fe8a0  r9=00000043cf7fe8e0 r10=00007ffc95c5869a
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000004000 r13=0000000000000001
r14=00000043cf7ff018 r15=000001bdf2856820
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69:
00007ffc`a6d0a859 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffca6d0a859 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000069)
   ExceptionCode: e0434352 (CLR exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 5
   Parameter[0]: ffffffff80070002
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[2]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[3]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[4]: 00007ffc95c50000

PROCESS_NAME:  Bookmark It.exe

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80070002

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 Bookmark_It!unknown_function+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  Bookmark_It!unknown_function

MODULE_NAME: Bookmark_It

IMAGE_NAME:  Bookmark_It.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ManagedPseudo ** Value: 1c6aeaf8000 ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.IO.FileNotFoundException_80070002_Bookmark_It.exe!unknown_function

OS_VERSION:  10.0.18362.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a5664d34-b1e3-4381-2c19-1c19445e489e}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

I can't really make anything from the analysis.

Comment: I have some questions. In my understanding, the UWP app will launch the win32 app and the crash comes from the WinForm app, right? So that the unhandled won't fire because the exception happens in the WinForm app. Have you tried to run the WinForm app directly to check if it will crash? Also, is it possible to confrim in which OS version the issue will happen?

Comment: No. I am not starting the winforms tray component on startup. I will start it only on the click of a button in uwp app. In this case, the uwp app itself crashes on launch.

Comment: Could you produce this in your own device when you download the app from the store and launch it?

Comment: Yes. It is crashing in all devices I've tested. I can give you the app details over DM if you need it.

Comment: Have you generated the symbol file when you packaged your app? If you did, you could use the symbol file to debug your app by attaching a debugger to the store downloaded app. Please refer to [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019) and [Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that. But since the app crashes, I am not able to attach debugger to running process. When i tried to debug installed app package, I faced an error "Unable to activate Windows store app. The process started but the activation request failed with the error - 'The app didn't start'". Checking the event viewer, reveals the same error mentioned in my question.

Comment: create a [crash dump with WER](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) and analyze the dmp with windbg

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am not able to figure it out from the crash dump analysis. I've updated my question with the analysis.

Comment: have you configured  Dump to be full dump (DumpType = 2)? looks you have a minidump. EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80070002 means ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Run ProcessMonitor in background and filter for filenotfound messages when you start your app,

Comment: Full crash dump analysis reveals this error msg - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-8216-system-private-corelib/ba-p/317201 @magicandre1981 Will try this. Looks like thats the problem

Comment: ok, try this and report back

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you post an answer on debugging the dumps so that I can award you the bounty?

Comment: ok, I posted the steps to generate dumps and analyze it.

Comment: I have this exact same error with a xamarin forms uwp app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MagicAndre1981 helped me in debugging the crash dump which revealed the error,

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

As Microsoft store no longer accepts mixed package (UWP + Desktop) binaries, We have to wrap it in a Visual Studio packaging project.

After adding a visual studio packaging project to the solution, I added my UWP and desktop projects as references to it. Then I moved my appservice and full trust process manifest definitions from UWP to the new Package project's manifest. Refer [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-8216-system-private-corelib/ba-p/317201) for more info.
After making these changes it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

To debug such issues, you should generate a crash dump. To do [this, you can use the Windows Error Reporting service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) of Windows.

To do this open regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps` key. Here you can create string `DumpFolder` to configure the location and the DWORD `DumpType` to configure the type. Here set the value to `2` for a full memory dump.

This configures global settings, to configure it per application use this location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\MyApplication.exe`.

No, open the dump in Windbg.exe, which is part of Windows 10 SDK, configure the [Debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run `!analyze -v`.

For pure UWP apps that show **0xC000027B** error, you should [use PDE.dll extension to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437625/1466046).