# Windows Store Submission issue - Duplicate build metadata files were found in the manifest of package

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I got a issue will trying to submit an application to the Windows Store.
After that I upload the ".msixupload" file. The package analyzer tell me:

```
Package acceptance validation error: Duplicate build metadata files were found in the manifest of package FriskPackaging_0.1.8.0_x64.msix: makepri.exe
```

Is someone have a idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the manifest file of your app?

Comment: Deep down the .msixupload package zip file the found a .msix file in witch I found AppxManifest.xml, in witch I found a duplicate "MakePri.exe" with 2 different version. In the <build:Metadata> section. How is that have append? How to fix this? Any idea?

Comment: It's hard to say. Could you please tell me what kind of application it is and how do you package your app?

Comment: It a C# UWP Application made with VS 2022, packaged with a "Windows Application Packaging Projet". Do you need other info?

Comment: If it is just only a UWP application, you could just package it without using WAPP, is there any other reason for using WAPP?

Comment: Now I got another error: 0x80080215 - Non appx extensions are not allowed for payload packages targeting older platforms. I will open another topic for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The was no need for an additional "Windows Application Packaging Projet"

Answer (score 2):

Removing the "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" package that comes with the Packaging Project solves the problem. This package is not mandatory.

The Windows Application Packaging Projet is required for example when including Win32 exe into an UWP project (runFullTrust capability) for publishing on the Store, otherwise the Store application can fail to start ( [Store version of UWP Package with a full trust process forms app keeps crashing on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168558/store-version-of-uwp-package-with-a-full-trust-process-forms-app-keeps-crashing) )

In the detail, as mentionned by Hugo the AppxManifest.xml from the .msixupload file contains two "Makepri.exe" in the "build:Metadata" section: one "MakePri.exe" (capital "M") and one "makePri.exe" (lower case "m"). The "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" package is responsible for the "makePri.exe", when checking its "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.props" file.

Removing the package doesn't result in errors when generating the Store package or using the application.